Having trouble adjusting the height of my card in bootstrap
<div class="card border-dark bg-white text-dark" style="width: 400px; height: auto; margin :10px auto ">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Register to REFILM</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form action="/register" method="post">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                {% if username_error %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    {{ username_error }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                {% if password_error %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    {{ password_error }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmation" placeholder="Confirm password">
                </div>
                {% if confirmation_error %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    {{ confirmation_error }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
                <div class="col text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


I'm creating a registration window using card properties in bootstrap. But it's very strange because the height of the card fills the screen.
I've tried settings like height: auto on parent tag and child tag, but it's still the same.

I would use a mixture of the utility classes and maximum-height custom style to generate this. Specifically a vh-100 to tell it to take up 100% of the horizontal viewport, but have "maximum-height:400px" in the style tag to put a cap on that of 400 pixels.
So, change your card tag to read:
<div class="card border-dark bg-white text-dark w-50 vh-100" style="max-height:400px" >


Thank you for the help, but it seems like my card doesn't depend on the amount of content and still always increases by the maximum height.

Solution :  remove for card-body tag
 style="height:300px"


I've already tried it, but it didn't work.

then why don't you update the code ?

working example is here - https://jsfiddle.net/krishna_kanth/rz27eLtn/

It looks like it's working well on the sample site, but for some reason it's not working well in my environment.

card-body  must have some css then it must be overriding from somewhere....

I just put the fit-content in the css tag and the height was automatically adjusted!
